# using .net regex parse string containing special chars such as "<>"

Tags: regex, parsing, keyword

folks, I want to parse a WCF service interface source code to generate its async version of Begin,End style. i.e. from the version below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExamManageService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void NewExam(ExamData ed);
    ...
}
```

generate new version like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExamManageService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginNewExam(ExamData ed, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndNewExam(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

I use the Regex to fulfill the parsing task. the match pattern is:

```
@"(?<oc>\[OperationContract.*?\])\s*?\r\n\s+?(?<ret>[\w\d_]+)\s+?(?<nam>[\w\d_]+?)\(((?<pn>[\w\d_]+?)\s+?(?<pv>[\w\d_]+?)(\s*?,\s*?)?)*?\);"
```

It goes well until It encountered this statement:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> GetIDCollection();
```

then the parser works not. Has anyone good idea to capture this piece "IEnumerable<Guid>" as a whole return value type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex pattern seems a bit overkill; a more simple approach should work:

```
(?m)(?<oc>\\[OperationContract.*?\\]$)|(?<n1>^.*;$)
```

Example:

**http://ideone.com/z0ve0O**

Pattern:

**http://regex101.com/r/vM8uZ5/1**

Comment: You are right, I am not skilled at using regex and silly to exclude <> with [\w\d_] and not on to it. Is regex101 your homepage? It is very cool for testing regular expression. I collected it. Thanks.